# Selenium Basico Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Saudações, sou iniciante em Selenium e segue abaixo o meu script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

links=['']
for link in links:

    browser=webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\Administrador\Downloads\chromedriver.exe')
    browser.execute_script("window.open('https://www.onlinevideoconverter.com/pt/youtube-converter');")
    time.sleep(1)

    ak=browser.find_element_by_id('texturl')
    ak.send_keys(link)

    au = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until( EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[text() = "Começar"]')) )
    au.click()

    af = WebDriverWait(browser, 90).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'downloadq'))
    )

    browser.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', af)
```

Que basicamente pega o link do download e o faz automaticamente.

O problema que acontece é que quando uso `browser.execute_script("window.open('https://www.onlinevideoconverter.com/pt/youtube-converter');")` o método `ak=browser.find_element_by_id('texturl')` não é carregado. Mesmo usando o `time.sleep`.

Queria saber se é possível resolver sem usar o `browser.get('https://www.onlinevideoconverter.com/pt/youtube-converter')`

O que está de errado?

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que ao usares o método `window.open()` o browser abre uma nova janela, então tens de dar instrução ao teu `webdriver` para mudar o foco para essa nova janela:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\Administrador\Downloads\chromedriver.exe')
browser.execute_script("window.open('https://www.onlinevideoconverter.com/pt/youtube-converter');")
time.sleep(1)

new_window = browser.window_handles[1]
browser.switch_to.window(new_window)

ak = WebDriverWait(browser, 90).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'texturl')))
ak.send_keys(link)
```